# UIScrollView contentOffset returns always zero in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I want to track the position of my horizontal scrollView, yet when I print the contentOffset.x or contentOffset, they always return zero.
This is the code for my class:

```
import UIKit

class ScrollForecast: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var scrollTemp: UILabel!

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print(self.contentOffset.x)

}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast

    let cellWidth: CGFloat = 40
    var index = round(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / cellWidth)
    targetContentOffset.pointee.x = index * cellWidth
}

}
```

Any ideas as to what might be the problem? The code inside scrollViewDidEndDragging works just fine and sets the contentOffset so that the scrollView snaps every 40 points.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `scrollView.contentSize` is large enough to allow it to scroll. Otherwise `targetContentOffset.pointee.x` will be zero.